# Publish Tridion asset to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: 2013

Is it possible to use Tridion 2013 to publish static content (jpg, xml, json) to an Amazon S3 bucket?

Anyone have any idea how this can be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: You are going to need to write either a storage extension or custom deployer I think. You could look at https://github.com/SI4T for reference. It stores content in the Broker DB and SOLR

Comment: @ChrisMorgan that would have been a valid answer, no need to only comment it.

Answer (score 9):

As you are using Tridion 2013, I would suggest that you also look at doing this using External Content Libraries (ECL), rather than through publishing.

Here are some advantage and disadvantages of this approach:

**Advantages:**

- Reduced CM database size (especially if you are storing large binaries or videos)
- Faster publishing (well, actually no publishing of the binaries!)
- Works better with outscaled publishing (You do not have to pick a Deployer to do the Custom Storage and have this slower than that others OR have the redundancy of every Deployer storing it)
- A single point of truth (the document is only in one place)
- You can still add metadata and Component Link to the document using the ECL stub Component
- Access to the content can be closely controlled within Tridion

**Disadvantages:**

- Editors will need a mechanism for accessing the Amazon S3 bucket to manage the documents.  This could be handled through the ECL provider.
- Additional Content Editor training (for both Tridion and Amazon S3)
- The document will not be versioned within Tridion (This may also complicate Workflow)
- You may need to configure Security with Amazon S3 AND Tridion

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you mean that through the ECL provider you upload the items in the Amazon S3 bucket (using the Create option in the CMS for a new ECL item) and then at publish time you utilize the direct link to the ECL item? I could see that working, sounds like a better solution than a storage extension in my opinion indeed.

Comment: @BartKoopman, yes, that is what I was thinking.

Comment: Very nice option indeed, I would suggest to make that a little more clear in your answer. Specifically, faster publishing will be no publishing of the item by Tridion, but just supplying a link. And the disadvantage of the editors needing a mechanism for accessing Amazon, is actually solved by the ECL provider if you make sure that the provider has the code to upload items to S3.

Comment: Thanks Bart.  I have added some tweaks to my answer.  Please feel free to amend with anything that you think I've missed.

Answer (score 6):

You should be writing a Storage Extension and custom Java code to publish to a custom data storage.

You may want to get an idea with this post from architectural perspective as how publishing process works with Custom Data Storage:

[Integrating-search-engines-with-sdl-tridion-2011](http://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/integrating-search-engines-with-sdl-tridion-2011/)

[Extending-content-delivery-storage-sdltridion-2011](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/extending-content-delivery-storage-sdltridion-2011-1.aspx)